# Error upon connection attempt to SQL Server 2005 via SSMS

Tags: sql-server-2005, windows-7, installation

I was able to install SQL 2005 x86 dev edition onto windows 7 Professional but cannot connect to the server via SSMS. I get

"Login Failed for user 'Compaq\username'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)"

Any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

This [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/sql_protocols/archive/2006/02/21/536201.aspx) might help. It says its due to a requirement to change the password for the account.

Also in the past with fresh install instances I have had problems on Win 7 if I did not run SSMS as admin with elevated privileges.

Answer (score 0):

Error 18456 means the login is not setup directly or via group in SQL Server *or* Compaq\username is not an admin (which should already have rights)

[How to fix with screenshots](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/05/06/sql-server-2005-fix-error-18456-vista-windows-authentication/)